# shared folders embedded in your OneDrive

Tags: c#, onedrive

Seems that you can not download / upload files from shared folders embedded in your OneDrive using OneDrive SDK c #.

Steps to simulate the behavior:

1. User "A" shares a Onedrive folder named "Shared01" with user "B"
   with "modify" permission;
2. User "B" incorporates "Shared01" into its own Onedrive: the folder
   "Shared01" appears in the root of "B";
3. Using the c# SDK (OneDriveApiBrowser.sln) and the user "B"
   credentials, the folder "Shared01" is correctly visible on the root,
   but:

If you navigate inside the folder "Shared01" the files stored in the folder are not displayed;

You can not upload/download or modify the files inside in the folder.

Also, if you try using the {item-id} of the files contained in "Shared01" through the request:

```
using (var stream = await this.oneDriveClient.Drive.Items[itemToOpen.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync())
```

Alias:

```
GET /drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

You get the following error:

```
"{Code: itemNotFoundThrow site: 29a3.1155Message: Item does not exist}"
```

In the past, that request worked.

Comment: Have you able to download the file using OneDrive web interface?

Comment: Yes of course. The problem is relative to OneDrive SDK C#.

Comment: In the past (few months ago) the id of the shared files in a folder embedded in OneDrive could be downloaded using `oneDriveClient.Drive.Items collection [itemToOpen.Id]`..., but not anymore!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

[This API documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/working-with-links.htm) explains it, and the concepts should map to your use of the SDK. Essentially, when you add a shared folder to your drive you're essentially adding a pointer. These pointers can be detected via the presence of the `remoteItem` facet, which will contain both the identity of the shared folder (`remoteItem.Id`) and the drive in which that folder resides (`remoteItem.parentReference.driveId`).

To query either the shared folder you'll need to construct a `drives` query using both of these pieces of information:

```
oneDriveClient.Drives[{remoteItem.parentReference.driveId}].Items[{remoteItem.Id}]
```

You can then get the children using:

```
oneDriveClient.Drives[{remoteItem.parentReference.driveId}].Items[{remoteItem.Id}].Children
```

And subsequently download a child using:

```
oneDriveClient.Drives[{remoteItem.parentReference.driveId}].Items[{remoteItem.Id}].Children[{child.name}]
```

OR

```
oneDriveClient.Drives[{remoteItem.parentReference.driveId}].Items[{child.Id}]
```

In the past using `drive` and `remoteItem.Id` *may* have worked, but that was definitely not the intention given the wrong drive was targeted.

Comment: Thanks, Brad.... But suppose you want to download a file in a shared folder from another user and embedded in our Onedrive {remoteItem}:
`using (var stream = await this.oneDriveClient.Drives[remoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId].Shared[remoteItem.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync())
{
...save file...
}`
The problem is that {remoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId]} seems to have the same value (in uppercase) of the drive associated with {remoteItem.Id}.

Comment: In my debug session i have:
remoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId="833de9ecab7004f0"
and
remoteItem.Id="833DE9ECAB7004F0!913"

Comment: Infact the above code "using..." generates an exception:

`{"Code: generalException\r\nThrow site: 37d7.8edc\r\nMessage: General Exception While Processing\r\n"}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    Error: {Code: generalException
Throw site: 37d7.8edc
Message: General Exception While Processing
}
    HResult: -2146233088
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Code: generalException\r\nThrow site: 37d7.8edc\r\nMessage: General Exception While Processing\r\n"...`

Comment: You wouldn't use `shared` in this case - think of it as a means to enumerate shared items. If you already know the `driveId` and `itemId` of an item that's shared to you, you just want to use `...Drives[driveId].Items[itemId]...` to access it

Comment: I'm having this same issue and can't get it to work. Is there any solution, yet?